# How to render list "LinkTitle" field using csr/jslink

Tags: sharepoint-online, jslink, title

the internal field name for "Title linked to item" is "LinkTitle" When added to a csr file though it's undefined.

```
function CustomItem(ctx) {
// Build a listitem entry for every item in the list.

var ret = "<div class='ms-rteFontSize-2 '>" + ctx.CurrentItem.LinkTitle + " 
<strong>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Start_x0020_Date + " </strong></div><br />";
return ret;
}
```

How do I display the title linked to dispform.aspx - the same as what shows in a default list view?

Answer (score 0):

I came across a property I didn't know existed - "displayFormUrl" and that did the trick. I couldn't use any of the "url path" options because the list view web part is on a page, so just reflected the page path, rather then the list's path. **displayFormUrl** returns the list url and all that's needed is to append the item id.

```
function CustomItem(ctx) {
// Build a listitem entry for every item in the list.

var ret = "<div class='ms-rteFontSize-2 '><a href='" + ctx.displayFormUrl + 
"&ID=" + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + "'><strong>" + 
ctx.CurrentItem.Start_x0020_Date + " - " + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + " 
</strong></a></div><br />";
return ret;
}
```